# How to trigger a modal popup from a php header?

Tags: php, html, forms, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to create a protection php page where visitor has to login before accessing a page. The visitor will be prompt to login with a modal form. May I know how I can achieve this?

Here is the anchor leading to community.php that will require login before access:

```
<a href="community.php" class="communityText" style="cursor: pointer;">Share your ideas with our community!</a>
```

Here is the community.php (I haven't built much of the page yet):

```
<?php include "protection.php" ?>

<?php include "webhead.php" ?>
```

Here is my protection php page:

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if($_SESSION['login_status'] != "ok") {

        header("location:modallogin.php");

    }

?>
```

Here is my modal html:

```
<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-login">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Please Login</h4>
            <p></p>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="loginModalName">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="loginModalName" placeholder="Please enter your username" required="required">
                        <p></p>
                        <label for="loginModalPassword">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="loginModalPassword" placeholder="Please enter your password" required="required">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block login-btn" style="background-color: #fdbf50 !important; color: #f4f4f8 !important;">Login</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer"><a href="#">Join us now!</a></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't handle this with a header call.

Comment: @ceejayoz how should I handle then?

Comment: JavaScript + AJAX calls, or a non-modal approach.

Answer (score -1):

Modal windows are displayed via Javascript on the client side, for example [like this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript). You need to send the user back to the home page with a toast message telling them to log in first.

Your redirect is not correct, HTTP requires a space after the `:` like this

```php
header("Location: modallogin.php");
```